# Parametro da requisição ajax sendo uma variavel

Tags: jquery

Olá, eu tenho uma pequena dúvida em como fazer isso:

```
$(function(){
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var tipo = $(this).attr("name");
    var text = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "minhaurl",
        data: {tipo: text},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result){
            $("#replaceResultSearch").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

});

repare que o parametro "tipo" vem do atributo "name" de um input (O usuário tem alguns inputs em uma tabela, e dependendo do que digita em cada input, ele busca no banco conforme essa coluna da tabela)
Mas quando passo "tipo" no ajax, ele trata esse "tipo" como o nome da requisição, e não o valor que ela tem (Pode ser "responsavel/assunto/data/etc") o que pode ser feito? obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você cria um objeto literal como `{tipo: text}`, as chaves **nunca** são variáveis. Portanto sua chave é "tipo" mesmo, e isso está sendo passado para o servidor. O único jeito de usar uma variável como chave é pela notação de colchetes:

```
var obj = {};
obj[tipo] = text;
```

Comment: Putz, verdade! tinha me esquecido disso, obrigado, resolveu meu problema!